# MySQL 5.7 Query to erase message content based on sent and response date

Tags: mysql

I'm having issues writing a query to erase the content of "inactive messages".
Erasing the content is just replacing the content of the message with "erased".

A message is considered inactive when:

1. The sent date < NOW - 720 days
2. AND the message response date < NOW - 720 days

This would be easy if I had the message response date, but I don't.
The only thing I have, is the "reply to message ID".
The response date on a message would be the sent date of the LAST response message.

If message with ID 3 is a reply to message with ID 2 which was a reply to message with ID 1, the response date of message with ID 1 would be the sent date of message with ID 3.

Here is the table:
[image: Table]

I tried this query to get all the "last" replies to messages but I'm not sure this will help me.

```
SELECT id, replyToMessage_id, sentDate
from Message OuterReference
where not exists (select 1 from Message where replyToMessage_id = OuterReference.ID)
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this

```sql
DELETE t1
FROM Message t1
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT replyToMessage_id, MAX(sentDate) MaxSentDate
            FROM Message t2
            GROUP BY replyToMessage_id ) t3 ON t3.replyToMessage_id IN (t1.id, t1.replyToMessage_id)
WHERE COALESCE(t3.MaxSentDate, t1.SentDate) < CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 2 YEAR
```

Subquery gets last responce date per message.

Joining condition joins the most last responce to the message and to all its responces.

Condition checks that this last responce date (for the messages which have no responces - the date of the message itself) it too old for to be removed.

The query assumes that responce date cannot be earlier than message date.

Comment: Hi Akina, thanks for your help. I was testing some cases for this query and found an issue.
It works good as long as I only have one reply to a message. It doesn't work when for example I have a message 3 which is a reply to message 2, which is a reply to message 1. If message 3 has been sent today, message 2 and message 1 should not be deleted.
In DB message 3 has replyToMessage_Id = 2 and message 2 has replyToMessage_Id = 1.

Comment: @Allinone51 Described situation needs in recursive gathering operation which cannot be performed in your MySQL version in single query format. Either upgrade your server till version 8+ or use iterative stored procedure.

Comment: Hi Akina, unfortunately updating is not an option. My query should be runned from a stored procedure, I'll have a look at how I can iterate through my messages. Thanks for your help